# What is making this simple Processing arithmetic fail?

Tags: java, math, processing

I am reading in serial values in Processing. An example:

```
...
297.5
297.1
297.1
...
```

These numbers do not vary by much more than shown here.

Then, I run the following code:

```
if (val > 100) {
    println(val);
}
```

It prints exactly what I have written above.

Then I run this code:

```
if (val > 100) {
    val -= 230;
    val *= 2;
    println(val);
}
```

It prints out wildly differing numbers:

```
...
-189.59998
136.0
-188.0
135.0
-190.0
...
```

Thinking that something was screwy with my math (but how?!), I reduced my code to this:

```
if (val > 100) {
    val -= 230;
    println(val);
}
```

It prints, as expected, 67ish.

What is wrong with `val *= 2`?!

The only thing I can think of is that I'm 'overflowing' the memory allocated for the `float` datatype and so it's 'rolling over' to be negative... But how is that possible? I thought Processing was just a thin skin over Java.

---

## Full Code

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial s;
float val;

void setup() {
    size(600, 400);
    String portName = Serial.list()[1];
    s = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
    s.bufferUntil('\n');
}

void draw() {
    if ( s.available() > 0) {
        try {
            val = Float.parseFloat(s.readStringUntil('\n').trim());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        
        if (val > 100) {
            val -= 230;
            val = val * 2.0;
            println(val);
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Pasted Input & Output

I have pasted the unabridged version of the outputs at the following site. The first is the output without the arithmetic; then there is a line of `###`, and then the values after arithmetic is performed.

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Du7TmZFv

Comment: Just a guess, but how about val *= 2.0;

Comment: That was my first thought too — unfortunately, no cigar! :(

Comment: float val = 297.1f;
  val -= 230;
     val *= 2;
     System.out.println(val); is working for me and result is 134.20001,

Comment: you must be doing something else outside the `if`, post all the code

Comment: Confirmed; works fine for me as well. There is probably something else wrong causing this. We will most likely need to see the entire code. Alternatively, set a debug point and a watch expression and step through the code, examining the result of your watch expression(s) at each point along the way and see if you can determine precisely where the error is occurring.

Comment: I posted the full code... Unfortunately, there's not much else going on (I tried to reduce it as much as possible for the sake of the question.)

Comment: I've also added a link to where I've pasted a large amount of the output and input for perusal.

Comment: Did you notice that, going backwards, -190/2=-95 and -95+230=135, you're keeping the previous result somewhere every other time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The culprit is `catch(Exception e){}`.  Never do this.

When your exception is thrown, `val` has the same value it had before.  I'm guessing you've got some blank lines, or some illegal values in your input stream.  Your program is failing to parse these as floats, throwing the exception, then just continuing onwards.

Comment: That was a spectacular catch, wow — thank you! I was so focused on minifying my code for the sake of posting this question that I removed my `catch` block — and thus gave myself a bigger problem than I had before. Whoops!